# Optimizing jquery sliders code to be more efficient

Tags: jquery, html

I have a feeling that my code can be reduced to a function that takes the parameters that are sent to it and do the job the same way rather than hard code a bunch of sliders that are identical but I have no idea how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    var $target1 = $('.target1');
    var $target2 = $('.target2');
    var $target3 = $('.target3');

    $target1.toggleClass('hidden1', sessionStorage.getItem('form_visible1') != 'true');
        $target2.toggleClass('hidden2', sessionStorage.getItem('form_visible2') != 'true');
        $target3.toggleClass('hidden3', sessionStorage.getItem('form_visible3') != 'true');

    $('.slide1').click(function() {
            $target1.slideToggle('slow', function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('hidden1');
            });

            sessionStorage.setItem('form_visible1', $target1.hasClass('hidden1'));
        });                             

        $('.slide2').click(function() {
            $target2.slideToggle('slow', function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('hidden2');
            });
            sessionStorage.setItem('form_visible2', $target2.hasClass('hidden2'));
        });                             

        $('.slide3').click(function() {
            $target3.slideToggle('slow', function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('hidden3');
            });
            sessionStorage.setItem('form_visible3', $target3.hasClass('hidden3'));
        });     
   });
```

html:

```
<div class="slide1">slider1</div> <div class="target1">test</div>

<div class="slide2">slider2</div> <div class="target2">test</div>

<div class="slide3">slider3</div> <div class="target3">test</div>
```

[**DEMO LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ADsL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just one of the idea of optimize, you can had a look, i change the html markup, css, and try the best not to change the sessionstorage

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2ADsL/2/

it is optimize enough? share the thought

```
$(function() {

    $('.target').each(function(i, v){
        var $i = i + 1;
        $(v).toggleClass('hidden',
         sessionStorage.getItem('form_visible' + $i) != 'true');
    });

    $('.slide').click(function(ev){
        var $ev = $(ev.currentTarget);
        var $next = $ev.next();

         $next.slideToggle('slow', function() {
              $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
         });
         sessionStorage.setItem('form_visible' + $ev.attr("id"), $next.hasClass('hidden'));
    });
});
```